# How to find the references of documented classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference

I always struggle with finding references for documented classes. Take the HardwareIdentification class for example. Ik can find the documentation just fine [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.profile.hardwareidentification). In the documentation it says the class is in the System.Windows.Profile library. When however I open the 'Add reference' box this library is not found in either 'Assemblies.Framwork' or 'Assemblies.Extensions'. My search on Google results in find nothing. The NuGet package manager doesn't find this assembly either. So where is it? It's not in the GAC too.

Comment: On top of your link it says: _"Docs -> Windows -> **UWP** -> API reference -> Windows.System.Profile -> HardwareIdentification"_. So it will be available in UWP application projects.

Comment: Ah, yep, missed that one. I'm not in UWP, that's why.

Answer (score 1):

The docs page mentions the Device Families and luckily provides the Windows SDK version that goes with that:

- Windows Desktop Extension SDK (introduced v10.0.10240.0)
- Windows Mobile Extension SDK (introduced v10.0.10240.0)
- Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (introduced v10.0.14393.0)

It also mentions that these Assemblies are for the WindowsRT / UWP development, it's likely these won't work elsewhere.

You can download the latest Windows SDK here:

- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

The default installation location is:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs

If you're using Visual Studio 2017, you may need to enable the correct workloads for the SDK elements to be installed, my workload, for example, doesn't contain UWP.

Comment: Thanks for the very specific answer. I was more or less looking for a more general approach on finding the libraries that contain functionality I need. With the amount of frameworks around it's hard to find your way through all the documentation and posts, etc.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, you'll likely a) know where it is b) have no clue. The docs don't make it any easier. Resharper has a "Magic import" feature that sometimes helps you out.